# RegEx to match a string of two words but not match t if it has the third

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to filter out the word cabbage when I have a string of words.

I want the following to match exactly. It must be this strong exactly:

```
apple banana
```

Only if it is that exactly. But sometimes I have a string that's is

```
apple banana cabbage
```

I don't want that to match at all. I don't want anything in that string to match.

I tried

```
/^apple banana$/
```

but it does not seem to work.

Any advice?

Comment: Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/CLq9tS/2)?

Comment: dear your question is not much explained but try this apple\s+banana

Comment: when you use `^`/`$`. You've to use multiline flag in your regex!

Comment: also leading `/` and trailing  `/` are a regex format for javascript not for C#/VB .net

Comment: Thanks guys. I appreciate it. I wrote this on a phone so I apologize for the terrible formatting. I am attempting to only match the string "apple banana" but, things like "oranges" I don't want to match. But, when it is "apple banana orange" together on a string I don't want it flagged.

Comment: @bulbus You are right! It worked! (?m)^(apple banana)$ will exclusively match what I want exactly and entirely, and not match anything else. A multiline flag was the answer!

Comment: Hey @bulbus , it won't let me choose your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?m)^apple banana$
```

1. Add multiline flag
2. Change format to .net remove leading trailing `/`